# KeyProperty or IntegerID Look-up to Model One-to-Many Relationship Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, one-to-many

this may be a super dumb question but here goes:

On App Engine, if I want to model a one-to-many relationship, should I store the referenced entity as a KeyProperty, or should I simply store the numericID of the entity (auto-generated by App Engine) as an Integery Property?

For example:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Author)

class Author(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

OR:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    author_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Author(ndb.Model):
    books = ndb.StringProperty()
```

In the second example, if I want to get the Author of a Book, I can do:

```
key = ndb.Key('Author', Book.author_id)
author = key.get()
```

Would one way be more efficient than the other? If the application is at a large scape, for example an Author can have 1 million books, and I needed to query for all the books for that Author, would one way be more efficient than the other?

I'm leaning toward the second way, simply because I feel it would be less storage to store the ID rather than a complex Key object, especially if I need to output JSON, it would be hard to serialize the Key object

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to produce Web-safe strings from keys, but keys do take much more space than IDs. There is no reason to use Keys for references with an exception of some rare use cases when you need to know the parent entity and decide that it's easier to store a full key than pass ID of an entity and ID of a parent (and maybe even parent of a parent) each time.

Also, if a property is included in composite indexes, the difference in size becomes even more significant.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Say I had a property on books, such as pages (IntegerProperty), and I wanted to sort by that property. So I had to query for all books with a numeric ID of an author, and then sort all the books by number of pages. For very large scale application, would you recommend the 2nd approach (storing numeric ID's)?

Comment: There won't be much difference in performance - just a bit because the data is shorter. Also, if you do a query right, it does not matter if you have 100 books or 1 million books - there is no reason to find more than a page full of results. The key difference is in storage space.